# How to integrate $cosec(x-\pi/3)cosec(x-\pi/6)$ from $0$ to $\pi/2$ using the properties of definite integrals?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

How to integrate $cosec(x-\pi/3)cosec(x-\pi/6)$ from $0$ to $\pi/2$ using the properties of definite integrals ?

I tried using $\pi/2-x$ in place of x but its of no use.Please help!

Comment: Don't you think that there is a problem with the definite integral ?

Comment: After converting it to sin and using $1/2[(sin(A+B)+sin(A-B)]$ we get $-π/6$ in the second bracket somethings wrong.